# MS Visio - Plug in (disable via registry)

Tags: ms-office, visio

I'm using MS Visio 2007 (on Windows XP sp3)

I just wanted to know if there is a registry key that controls the “turning on and off” of the COM Add-In? I've got a plug-in  and want to disable for "some" of my users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a registry key for exactly that, for each COM Addin.

In particular:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visio\AddIns\YourAddinName\LoadBehavior
```

See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106(v=vs.100).aspx